# How can I get a range of dates in php?

Tags: php

```
$start_date = '2012-01-01';
$end_date = '2012-12-31';
$total_days = round(abs(strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date)) / 86400, 0) + 1;

if ($end_date >= $start_date)
{
  for ($day = 0; $day < $total_days; $day++)
  {
    echo "<br />" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$start_date} + {day} days"));
  }
}
```

Right now that's printing '1969-12-31' over and over. The expected output should be:

```
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
2012-01-03
...
2012-12-30
2012-12-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You above code will work with one extra character - you missed a `$` on this line:

```
echo "<br />" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$start_date} + {$day} days"));
//                                                        ^ This was missing
```

Comment: @AllisonChristiansen: You should accept it as the answer then.

Comment: Yeah I know, it wouldn't let me for the first five minutes and I went on to do other things. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class (along with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)) for this:

```
$start_date = '2012-01-01';
$end_date = '2012-12-31';

$start    = new DateTime($start_date);
$end      = new DateTime($end_date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 day interval
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    // Do stuff with each $day...
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$start_date = '2012-01-01';
$end_date = '2012-12-31';
$total_days = round(abs(strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date)) / 86400, 0) + 1;

if ($end_date >= $start_date)
{
  for ($day = 0; $day < $total_days; $day++)
  {
    echo "<br />" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$start_date} + {$day} days"));
                                 //     You missed the $ here ^
  }
}
```