# PHP add 45 Minutes to a Time with Loop

Tags: php, time

I'm preparing an appointment script for entering visiting start hours and end hours like 09:00 and 20:00 and each visit period is 45 minutes.

I want to add 45 minutes from start time to end time within a loop. But with samples on internet I couldn't do it.

Visiting times are dynamic I mean it could be 09:00-20:00 or 11:00-23:00 etc.

The exact solution I'm trying to do is:

```
$visit_start = '09:00';
$visit_end   = '20:00';
$difference  =  $visit_end - $visit_start;
$i = 1;
while( $i <= $difference )
{
    print $visit_hour_list = $visit_start + 45;
    $i++;
}
```

and the print out will be like:

```
09:00
09:45
10:30
11:15
12:00
```

until to end hour. But I have no clue how that could work.

Comment: Have you read about PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)? (Specifically http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: It is all in one class: http://php.net/class.dateperiod - You set the Start and Endtime (like you have: 9 & 20 or 11 & 23) and the interval (like you have: 45 minutes) and you're done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991428/367456) in the similar question [*"How can I get a range of dates in php?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8990941/367456), you can make use of the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/DatePeriod) class in PHP to iterate over each 45 minute times' between a start and end time:

[Demo](https://eval.in/54754):

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP add 45 Minutes to a Time with Loop
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399907/367456
 */

$begin = new DateTime("09:00");
$end   = new DateTime("20:00");

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('45 min');

$times    = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($times as $time) {
    echo $time->format('H:i'), '-', 
         $time->add($interval)->format('H:i'), "\n"
         ;
}
```

Output:

```
09:00-09:45
09:45-10:30
10:30-11:15
11:15-12:00
12:00-12:45
12:45-13:30
13:30-14:15
14:15-15:00
15:00-15:45
15:45-16:30
16:30-17:15
17:15-18:00
18:00-18:45
18:45-19:30
19:30-20:15
```

Comment: The code is originally by user1281385, you need to thank him. You should also see that this has been answered before, probably you should more thoroughly look, *any* PHP date/time question has been answered already. Believe me.

Comment: thanks to him, and i'll be more carefull next time, thanks again.

Comment: This is the correct way, indeed (a lot better than my approach). So, +1. And @hakre, nice edit :)

Comment: If user uses timezone that uses DST, problem may arise, [demo](https://eval.in/54881). Quick fix would be to set timezone that doesn't use DST, like [demo](https://eval.in/54884).

Comment: that's wanted behavior. the fix version is worse imo

Comment: For you maybe this is wanted behavior, for others it might not be. Go ahead and provide better fix, let me learn something new.

Comment: Its not the user whos timezone would dictate this, Its the server one. If your in a DST your bookings suggest its going to be too long / too short depending on which DST change happens.

Comment: @user1281385: as `If user uses timezone that uses DST` I meant as `If developer uses timezone`, not user as webpage visitor...